# Unity UWP XAML build when deployed on Local Machine app button is not responding to Mouse Click

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp-xaml, hololens, mrtk

It is a 3d application using MRTK. The PC build is responding to Mouse Click. But in the UWP build for XAML project, the buttons in the application are not recognizing mouse click. Though it is taking input from keyboard and from touch screen.
Unity: 2019
Visual Studio: 2019
Build Type: UWP- XAML project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MRTK is designed specifically for mixed reality experience, it currently does not support building to a 2D desktop platform, we should deploy and test on the HoloLens device or emulator.

For Build Type, our recommendation is to use `D3D` unless you are using the `TouchScreenKeyboard` API in your project to use the system keyboard, you need to export as XAML.

If you want to use mouse input in HoloLens device(such as pair a Bluetooth mouse with the HoloLens2 device) you can enable this feature in MRTK by adding a new Input Data Provider of type `MouseDeviceManager` to the `MRTK input profile` and assigning the `MixedRealityMouseInputProfile` to the data provider. After that, the `MousePointer` will power a screen to world raycast for far interactions, more information please see: [Pointers](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Pointers.html#far-pointers)